# Buffer road line, taking into consideration elevation and upslope/downslope

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, buffer, elevation, slope

I have a roads polyline layer. I have vector-based contour lines. I have converted those contours to a TIN, then created a raster based on that TIN. Now I have my roads and my elevation raster. Now I need a 200ft buffer on the upslope and a 150ft buffer on the downslope. There are many posts regarding this...but nothing simple. I need step by step directions.

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 Advanced with all the bells and whistles.

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?  If so, I think that should be mentioned specifically and amongst your tags. Otherwise some potential answerers are likely to miss seeing your question.

Comment: What is at least one of the "many posts regarding this" that you have seen?  Potential answerers are more likely to help if they do not have to guess what you have already seen and discounted first.  Don't forget to take the 2-minute [Tour] to become familiar with the site's protocols.